# How much is my Nicaraguan money worth in US dollars?

Tags: money, exchange, nicaragua

I have a 20,000 Banca Central de Nicaragua Veinte Mil cordobas bill how much in U.S. dollars can I get for this?

Comment: I am not sure if the question is on topic, but it is actually not a duplicate. There is no current 20,000 córdoba bill, so the bill must be of one of the earlier "versions" of the córdoba. The last time the córdoba was redenominated was in the late eighties with 1,000 old córdobas to 1 new córdoba oro.

Comment: I am not sure if currency questions are on topic at all (or at least if they should be on topic here). Due to fluctuations, an answer may be outdated within days and it is extremely easy to find current and up to date exchange rates with Google or any other search engine.

Comment: Even if on topic, it needs to be reworded before being reopened, otherwise it should be immediately closed again as any answer would change almost immediately.  It should be "how could I calculate the value of x Nicaraguan currency", and an answer would include a link to xe.com or something.  If it's not legal tender, then we're evaluating the value of an item, which isn't travel, IMHO. :/

Answer (score 0):

[Google](http://www.google.com) can answer exchange rates in many currencies! Just type "20000 cordobas to us dollars" in the search box and you'll get the amount in Us Dollars you have.